# Run Azure Logic app only first 5 days per month

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

as i mentioned in the topic i need to run a trigger only first 5 days of each month. Any ideas how to do it?
I tried to check with Recurrence trigger but did not find how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share us any screen shot what you have tried

Comment: what have you tried so far ?some cron expressiona ?

Comment: is it possible to use Recurrence trigger for it? I can not find good standard option for it. I of course can run it every day and check if Day is equal 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 but do you have some another solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Recurrence documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence?tabs=consumption#workflow-definition---recurrence), it looks like you can specify a monthly recurrence with `monthDays` using the JSON definition.

Worth trying something like :

```
"triggers": {
    "Recurrence": {
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Month",
            "interval": 1,
            "schedule": {
                "monthDays": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            }
        },
        "type": "Recurrence"
    }
}
```

While setting this up, keep in mind the following though :

[image: Set recurrence in advance explanation]

Comment: thank you for the answer. Did you try this solution? I tried but seems to be not working..